# How come my AngularJS is not working, is it my filter function?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-filter

I am trying to work my `ng-repeat` with my filter. It is not working as I had hoped. I was wondering if it is not possible to be doing what I am trying to do??
My html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search">

<div class='col-md-12' ng-repeat='(key,value) in cropplans | contains:search.text'> <h4> Title: key</h4>
</div>
```

And here is my controller and filter:

```
aggriApp.filter('contains', function() {
  return function(values, field) {
        var result = {};
  field = field.toLowerCase()
  angular.forEach(values, function(key, value) {
      if(value.company_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(field) >= 0){
           result[key] = value
            }
        });
  return result
```

**EDIT:** When I type into the search input, I am not getting any changes with the filter that I have applied. If the search doesn't match I should be getting 0 results right?

**EDIT:**
`$scope.cropplans` is an object that looks similar to:

```
Object
AkshaYagna: Array(1)
0:
$$hashKey: "object:2684"
active: true
area: "0.00000"
block: {id: 230, name: "default", farm: {…}}
certification: null
closing_reason: null
company_name: "AkshaYagna"
created: "2019-01-17T21:04:23.605311Z"
crop_forecast: [{…}]
estimated_cases_count: 2000
estimated_harvest_date: "2019-01-17"
estimated_harvest_date_end: "2019-02-28"
foodhub: 409
foodhub_seller: 3752
foodhub_transport_time: 0
id: 828
modified: "2019-01-17T21:04:23.605319Z"
planting_date: null
plu_code: {id: 12891, commodity: "Conventional Baby Bok Choy", variety: "Shanghai", size: "30#", package: "Cartons", …}
received_cases: null
received_on: null
user: {id: 4022, email: "asus@lenovo.com", first_name: "Child.farm", last_name: "06", telephone: null, …}
__proto__: Object
received: 0
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
Child.farm03: [{…}, received: 0]
Samuel Gibbs: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}, received: 0]
shadow test: (2) [{…}, {…}, received: 0]
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: Updated. Basically, the filter isn't applying. Say I type in 'farmer' I hope that the ng-repeat applies to and all items with 'farmer' in the company_name would show up?

Comment: can you provide what you have in $scope.cropplans

Comment: Added in edit. You know what. I think it might be because the value is an array... But even though it is, if I type something that doesn't match then it should return empty correct?

Comment: post the array in JSON format. the output of console.log($scope.cropplans);

Comment: Added! I just copied and pasted, is there another way i shouldve done it

Answer (score 0):

For filtering you array by company name there is no need to write your own filter, You can use angularjs filter filter with an object. Try the following

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search">

<div class='col-md-12' ng-repeat="(key,value) in cropplans | filter : {'company_name' : search.text}"> 
    <h4> {{value}}</h4>
</div>
```

It is case insensitive so you do not have to worry about converting to lower case / upper case.

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing it correctly but I got this:
`angular.js:12722 Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received:`
Along with the whole object of $scope.cropplans

Comment: As the error says you need to return an array but you are returning an object, you will have to change that part

Comment: The thing is, a lot of my current app is running off of this object. This is also why I decided to write my own filter.

Comment: check the following page https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray  , you can use toArrayFilter

Comment: No luck... I am not sure what I might be doing wrong